# Clipping Feature Classes by Data View Extents with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, clip, extents

Have a fully functional script about 90% of the time. It is that 10% that is really bothering me and I cannot seem to deduce a solution.

Script will take the user defined dataframe view extents and clip all layers within extent to a geodatabase. That 10% failure rate occurs when clipping an extent that does not contain one of the features (gate_line, fence_line, or wall_line).

My thinking would be to limit input for clipping to only layers that are found in the view extents, this is where I logically fail.

The current script:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

#overwrite permissions
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#set map document to current
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
path = mxd.filePath
path = path.replace(os.path.basename(path),"") 
arcpy.env.workspace = path

#creates new file geoGDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(path, "CurrentExtents.gdb")
gdb = path + "CurrentExtents.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb


#set dataframe extents as a polygon
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
dfAsFeature = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([df.extent.lowerLeft,
                                         df.extent.lowerRight,
                                         df.extent.upperRight,
                                         df.extent.upperLeft]), df.spatialReference)

lyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df)


exportLayers = []
for lyr in lyrs:
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer == True:  
        layerRplc = lyr.longName  
        replace = [".", "\\"]
        result = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr)
        count = int(result.getOutput(0))
#Only include non-blank features
        if count != 0:   
            for item in replace:  
                layerRplc = layerRplc.replace(item, "_")  
            outFC = os.path.join(gdb,layerRplc) 
            exportLayers.append(outFC)
            if arcpy.Exists(outFC):
                arcpy.Delete_management(outFC)
            arcpy.AddMessage("Getting our clip on...." + outFC)
            clip = arcpy.Clip_analysis(lyr, dfAsFeature, outFC)
#removes empty fc's from gdb
            clipRes = arcpy.GetCount_management(clip)
            clipCount = int(clipRes.getOutput(0))
            if clipCount == 0:
                arcpy.Delete_management(clip)
            del replace
    del lyr

del mxd
del df
```

Script is run in desktop from catalog with a saved mxd directory as the defined workspace.

Just started coding recently!

Comment: Clip_management doesn't produce an output, clip = arcpy.Clip_analysis(lyr, dfAsFeature, outFC) is not right, so your clipRes = arcpy.GetCount_management(clip) should be clipRes = arcpy.GetCount_management(outFC) but I think the problem may spring from del replace, or its indentation level, you don't need to delete it.

Comment: Oh, right on @MichaelMiles-Stimson, I believe that del replace is an artifact from something else I was trying before and it never made its way out.

Comment: I'd use 1. env.extent= df.extent 2. Instead of clip use copy features. 3. Check records count in output and delete if 0.